# Function has no objects member pylint

Tags: django

I am using django 3 i am getting Function product has no object member error in this objects.all() method in my views.py file can anyone help please

```
from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
from .models import models



def pro(request):
 pro = **product**.objects.all()
return render(request , 'accounts/pro.html' , {'product' : pro})
```

MODELS.PY

```
class product(models.Model):
 CATEGORY= (

    ('InDoor' , 'InDoor'),
    ('OutDoor' , 'OutDoor'),
)
name= models.CharField(max_length = 245 , null=True)
price= models.FloatField(null = True)
category= models.CharField(max_length=245 , null=True , choices = CATEGORY)
description=models.CharField(max_length=500 , null= True , blank=True)
date_created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True , null = True )
tags=models.ManyToManyField(tag)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Comment: `product.objects.all()` no need to `**` side note: you should name your classes with title case per pep8 rules.  `class Product(models.Model)`

Comment: Thanks But now i am getting name error (name Product is not defined any idea how to fix that?)               **

Comment: Your import statement is incorrect it should be:

from .models import *